# Integrated Auth working randomly with ADFS server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, internet-explorer, adfs, integrated-authentication

We have a working ADFS server that is allowing some users to authenticate to a SP through WIA, but some folks are being directed to the ADFS login page for the RPT. Users can then log in there and directed back to the SP just fine.

It's not a user issue because I can log onto one workstation and use WIA just fine, but then get redirected to the login page on another. I verified its not a browser version issue.

GPO enable WIA in IE, add SP and ADFS domains to Trusted and Local Intranet Lists.

Although the error is not directly related -- I verified that we have all of the recommendations in this Support article in place https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3044976.

Has anyone experienced this before?